# How to call a function in super class, which is already overridden in child class, using the object of child Class in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, overriding

I have 2 classes **Parent** and **Child**. Both the classes contain method *myMethod*. I'm creating the object of **Child** class in the another class **ClassA**. My issue is I need the call the *myMethod* of the **Parent** class using the object of **Child** class from class **ClassA**.

Hope I could convey my doubt properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly call a super class method of an object from outside of its class.  To be honest, the fact that you need to do this is a code smell.  Rethink your design.

If you add some detail as to why you are trying to do this, we might be able to help.